# Static verification limitations when using pure functions in C# code contracts?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm trying to statically verify the following partial implementation of an array-based stack with code contracts. The method `Pop()` uses the pure function `IsNotEmpty()` to ensure that the subsequent array access will be at/above the lower bound. The static verifier fails and suggests that I add the precondition `Contract.Requires(0 <= this.top)`.

Can anyone explain why the verifier cannot prove the array access is valid with respect to the lower bound given the contract `IsNotEmpty()`?

At first I thought the `Contract.Requires(IsNotEmpty())` approach might be incorrect because a subclass could override `IsNotEmpty()`. However, the verifier still can't prove the array access is valid if I mark the class as `sealed`.

**Update:** If I change `IsNotEmpty()` to a read-only property, the verification succeeds as expected. This raises the question: *how / why are read-only properties and pure functions treated differently?*

```
class StackAr<T>
{
    private T[] data;
    private int capacity;

    /// <summary>
    /// the index of the top array element
    /// </summary>
    private int top;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(data != null);
        Contract.Invariant(top < capacity);
        Contract.Invariant(top >= -1);
        Contract.Invariant(capacity == data.Length);
    }

    public StackAr(int capacity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(capacity > 0);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.data = new T[capacity];
        top = -1;
    }

    [Pure]
    public bool IsNotEmpty()
    {
        return 0 <= this.top;
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        Contract.Requires(IsNotEmpty());

        //CodeContracts: Suggested precondition: 
        //Contract.Requires(0 <= this.top);

        T element = data[top];
        top--;
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I am a bit disappointed with Code Contracts...

Comment: ChaosPandion, what is there to be disappointed about?

Comment: even when the class is not marked `sealed`, inheriting classes *cannot* override `IsNotEmpty` because it’s not marked `virtual`, so no problem there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
[Pure]
public bool IsNotEmpty() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<bool>() && 0 <= this.top || !Contract.Result<bool>() && 0 > this.top);
    return 0 <= this.top;
}
```

See this thread on the code contracts forum for more information: [Calling a method in Contract.Requires](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/805dd6c1-d571-44b2-819b-10114d7306e5)

**Edit:**

Another solution to this problem, as mentioned in the thread linked above, is the `-infer` command line option:

> Now, inferring the post condition of this method is possible, and in fact we do have the option to do so: try to add -infer ensures on the extra options line in the contract property pane for the static checker.

I have checked, and this does resolve the problem. If you look in the [code contracts manual](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf), you'll see that the default option is to only infer property post-conditions. By using this switch, you can tell it to attempt to infer the post-conditions of methods too:

> -infer (requires + propertyensures + methodensures) (default=propertyensures)

Comment: Thanks Rich, do you know why properties behave differently?

Comment: The condition is more simply written as: `Contract.Result<bool>() == (0 <= this.top)`.